# Need help for finding optimal path which visits multiple sequences of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, pseudocode, path-finding

#### Summary

Recently I have had a path-finding puzzle that has some complex constraints (currently, I don't have any solution for this one)

- A 2D matrix represented the graph. The length of a path is the number of traversed cells.
- One or more **number sequences** are to be found inside the matrix. Each sequence is scored with a value.
- Maximum length of the path in the graph. The number of picked cells must not exceed this value.
- At any given moment, you can only choose cells in a specific column or row.
- On each turn, you need to switch between column and row and stay on
  the same line as the last cell you picked. You have to move at right angles. (**The direction is like the Snake game**).
- Always start with picking the first cell from the top row, then go
  vertically down to pick the second cell, and then continue switching
  between column and row as usual.
- You can't choose the same cell twice. The resulting path must not contain duplicated
  cells.

For example:
[image]

The task is to find the **shortest path, if possible** in the graph that **contains one or more sequences** with the **highest total score** and **the path's length is not exceed the provided maximum length**.

The picture below demonstrates the solved puzzle with the resulting path marked in red:

[image]

Here, we have a path **3A-10-9B**. This path contains the given
sequence **3A-10-9B** so, which earns 10pts. More complex graphs typically have longer paths containing various sequences at once.

#### More complex examples

##### Multiple Sequences

[image]

You can complete sequences in any order. The order in which the sequences are listed doesn't matter.

##### Wasted Moves

Sometimes we are forced to waste moves and choose different cells that don't belong to any sequence. Here are the rules:

- Able to waste 1 or 2 moves before the first sequence.
- Able to waste 1 or 2 moves between any neighboring sequences.
- However, you cannot break sequences and waste moves in the middle of them.

[image]

Here, we must waste one move before the sequence **3A-9B** and two moves between sequences **3A-9B** and **72-D4**. Also, notice how red lines between **3A** and **9B** as well as between **72** and **D4** "cross" previously selected cells **D4** and **9B**, respectively. You can pick different cells from the same row or column multiple times.

##### Optimal Sequences

Sometimes, it is not possible to have a path that contains all of the provided sequences. In this case, choose the way which achieved the most significant score.

[image]

In the above example, we can complete either **9B-3A-72-D4** or **72-D4-3A** but not both due to the maximum path length of 5 cells. We have chosen the sequence **9B-3A-72-D4** since it grants more score points than **72-D4-3A**.

##### Unsolvable solution

[image]

The first sequence **3A-D4** can't be completed since the code matrix doesn't contain code **D4** at all. The second sequence, **72-10**, can't be completed for another reason: codes **72** and **10** aren't located in the same row or column anywhere in the matrix and, therefore, can't form a sequence.

#### Performance advice

One brute force way is to generate all possible paths in the code matrix, loop through them and choose the best one. This is the easiest but also the slowest approach. Solving larger matrices with larger maximum length of path might take dozens of minutes, if not hours.

Try to implement a faster algorithm that doesn’t iterate through all possible paths and can solve puzzles with the following parameters in less than 10 seconds:

- Matrix size: 10x10
- Number of sequences: 5
- Average length of sequences: 4
- Maximum path length: 12
- At least one solution exists

For example:

```
Matrix:
41,0f,32,18,29,4b,55,3f,10,3a,
19,4f,57,43,3a,25,19,1e,5e,42,
13,5a,54,3c,1b,32,29,1c,15,30,
49,45,22,2e,25,51,2f,21,4c,37,
1a,5e,49,12,55,1e,49,19,43,2d,
34,26,53,48,49,60,32,3c,50,10,
0f,1e,30,3d,64,37,5b,5e,22,61,
4e,4f,15,5a,13,56,44,22,40,26,
43,2c,17,2b,1f,25,43,60,50,1f,
3c,2b,54,46,42,4d,32,46,30,24,

Sequences:
30, 26, 44, 32, 3c - 25pts
5a, 3c, 12, 1e, 4d - 10pts 
1e, 5a, 12 - 10pts
4d, 1e - 5pts
32, 51, 2f, 49, 55, 42 - 30pts

Optimal solution
3f, 1c, 30, 26, 44, 32, 3c, 22, 5a, 12, 1e, 4d
Which contains
30, 26, 44, 32, 3c
5a, 12, 1e
1e, 4d
```

#### Conclusion

I am looking for any advice for this puzzle since I have no idea what keywords to look for. A pseudo-code or hints would be helpful for me, and I appreciate that. What has come to my mind is just Dijkstra:

- For each sequence, since the order doesn't matter, I have to find all get all possible paths with every permutation, then find the highest score path that contains other input sequences
- After that, choose the best of the best.

In this case, I doubt the performance will be the issue.

Comment: What about simply search the space of all possible moves? (you could use BFS, DFS, A*, ... to do so).

Comment: Do you mean: for each sequence, get all possible paths, then find the highest score path that contains other input sequences? After that, choose the best of the best. If it is the case, I doubt the performance will be the issue.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/157459/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75410318/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

First step is to find if a required sequence exists.

```
- SET found FALSE
- LOOP C1 over cells in first row
     - CLEAR foundSequence
     - ADD C1 to foundSequence
     - LOOP C2 over cells is column containing C1
         - IF C2 value == first value in sequence
             - ADD C2 to foundSequence
             - SET found TRUE
             - break from LOOP C2
     - IF found 
          - SET direction VERT
          - LOOP V over remaining values in sequence
               - TOGGLE direction
               - SET found FALSE
               - LOOP C2 over cells in same column or row ( depending on direction ) containing last cell in foundSequence
                     - IF C2 value == V
                          - ADD C2 to foundSequence
                          - SET found TRUE
                          - break from LOOP C2
               - IF ! found
                      break out of LOOP V
- IF foundSequence == required sequence
       - RETURN foundSequence
RETURN failed
```

Note: this doesn't find sequences that are feasible with "wasted moves".  I would implement this first and get it working.  Then, using the same ideas, it can be extended to allow wasted moves.

You have not specified an input format!  I suggest a space delimited text files with lines beginning with 'm' containing matrix values and lines beginning 's' containing sequences, like this

```
m 3A 3A 10 9B
m 9B 72 3A 10
m 10 3A 3A 3A
m 3A 10 3A 9B
s 3A 10 9B
```

I have implemented the sequence finder in C++

```
std::vector<int> findSequence()
{
    int w, h;
    pA->size(w, h);
    std::vector<int> foundSequence;
    bool found = false;
    bool vert = false;

    // loop over cells in first row
    for (int c = 0; c < w; c++)
    {
        foundSequence.clear();
        found = false;

        if (pA->cell(c, 0)->value == vSequence[0][0])
        {
            foundSequence.push_back(pA->cell(c, 0)->ID());
            found = true;
        }

        while (found) 
        {
            // found possible starting cell

            // toggle search direction
            vert = (!vert);

            // start from last cell found
            auto pmCell = pA->cell(foundSequence.back());
            int c, r;
            pA->coords(c, r, pmCell);

            // look for next value in required sequence
            std::string nextValue = vSequence[0][foundSequence.size()];
            found = false;

            if (vert)
            {
                // loop over cells in column
                for (int r2 = 1; r2 < w; r2++)
                {
                    if (pA->cell(c, r2)->value == nextValue)
                    {
                        foundSequence.push_back(pA->cell(c, r2)->ID());
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // loop over cells in row
                for (int c2 = 0; c2 < h; c2++)
                {
                    if (pA->cell(c2, r)->value == nextValue)
                    {
                        foundSequence.push_back(pA->cell(c2, r)->ID());
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                // dead end - try starting from next cell in first row
                break;
            }

            if( foundSequence.size() == vSequence[0].size()) {

                // success!!!
                return foundSequence;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Cannot find sequence\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

This outputs:

```
3A 3A 10 9B
9B 72 3A 10
10 3A 3A 3A
3A 10 3A 9B

row 0 col 1 3A
row 3 col 1 10
row 3 col 3 9B
```

You can check out the code for the complete application at https://github.com/JamesBremner/stackoverflow75410318

I have added the ability to find sequences that start elsewhere than the first row ( i.e. with "wasted moves" ).  You can see the code in the github repo.

Here are the the results of a timing profile run on a 10 by 10 matrix - the algorithm finds 5 sequences in 0.6 milliseconds

```
Searching
41 0f 32 18 29 4b 55 3f 10 3a
19 4f 57 43 3a 25 19 1e 5e 42
13 5a 54 3c 1b 32 29 1c 15 30
49 45 22 2e 25 51 2f 21 4c 37
1a 5e 49 12 55 1e 49 19 43 2d
34 26 53 48 49 60 32 3c 50 10
0f 1e 30 3d 64 37 5b 5e 22 61
4e 4f 15 5a 13 56 44 22 40 26
43 2c 17 2b 1f 25 43 60 50 1f
3c 2b 54 46 42 4d 32 46 30 24

for sequence 4d 1e

Cannot find sequence starting in 1st row, using wasted moves
row 9 col 5 4d
row 4 col 5 1e

for sequence 30 26 44 32 3c

Cannot find sequence starting in 1st row, using wasted moves
Cannot find sequence

for sequence 5a 3c 12 1e 4d

Cannot find sequence starting in 1st row, using wasted moves
row 2 col 1 5a
row 2 col 3 3c
row 4 col 3 12
row 4 col 5 1e
row 9 col 5 4d

for sequence 1e 5a 12

Cannot find sequence starting in 1st row, using wasted moves
row 6 col 1 1e
row 4 col 5 1e
row 4 col 3 12

for sequence 32 51 2f 49 55 42

Cannot find sequence starting in 1st row, using wasted moves
row 2 col 5 32
row 3 col 5 51
row 3 col 6 2f
row 4 col 6 49
row 4 col 4 55
row 9 col 4 42

raven::set::cRunWatch code timing profile
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       5        0.00059034      0.0029517       findSequence
```

Comment: Thanks for your example; I have edited the "performance consideration" section on the post. You can check it later. From your snippet, I don't think a naive iteration will meet the performance requirements, though I don't have an example for such large input.

Comment: A 10 by 10 matrix is fairly small.  I expect this would be handled in a few seconds.  Please post a 10 by 10 example in the input format I have suggested - I will run a timing test for you.

Comment: Added a simple timing test run.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I have provided an example in the edited post. Could you try it?

Comment: I have converted your 10 by 10 sample to the input format I requested. https://github.com/JamesBremner/stackoverflow75410318/blob/main/data/data3.txt

Comment: None of the sequences in your example can be found without using "wasted moves"

Comment: I have added an issue for the wasted move enhancement. https://github.com/JamesBremner/stackoverflow75410318/issues/1

Comment: Posted timing results for your 10 by 10 example, finding 5 sequences buried in the middle of the matrix.

Comment: I have added a method to display the 'wasted moves' reuired to reach the sequence start from the first row.  See the output at https://github.com/JamesBremner/stackoverflow75410318/issues/1#issuecomment-1427075507